# gdb: howto speedup debugging on a very large binary?

Tags: gdb

Is there a way to speed up gdb when it loads a very large c++ binary?

The binary I am talking about is about 50MB in a release build (no debug symbols)

A debug build is bigger then 400MB and gdb needs more then 2 minutes to load it.

Maybe there are some settings that speed up loading the application into gdb ?

Any help is very appreciated!

Environment: ubuntu karmic 64bit with gdb v6.8, 32GB Ram, 8 cpu-cores

Comment: @Seth - on powerpc/sparc it is nearly 1GB ...

Comment: @Vokuhila-Oliba Are you using `LD_BIND_NOW`?

Comment: LD_BIND_NOW is not specified, - at least not explictly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin by upgrading to [GDB 7.0.1](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/). GDB developers have spent quite a bit of effort in 2009 making GDB 7.0 faster (and there is more to come in 7.1 :-)